# "We have shortly coming..."

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, parsing

These are lines from the movie *Dumb and Dumber*:

> This is the Hotel Danbury Presidential Suite, gentlemen, normally reserved for royalty, visiting dignitaries, illustrious stars of stage and screen. **We have shortly coming** the Emperor and Empress of Japan, and of course, Princess Charles and Di when they were together used to frequent the hotel constantly. ([YouTube clip](https://youtu.be/OSJShhHwy94?t=23))

I can't seem to parse *"We have shortly coming ..."* While the meaning of the entire sentence appears clear, what does "have shortly coming" mean? How should the sentence be parsed? I can't even make out phrases in that part of the sentence.

Comment: As a non-native speaker, I guess the object of "have" in the bold part is **"the Emperor and Empress of Japan, and Princess Charles and Di"**, and **"shortly coming"** is the object complement modifying the object. **"shortly coming"** seems to be instinctively placed before its object because the object is too long.

Comment: @Floret I think you got it. Would you put that in an answer?

Comment: It's a normal adverb/verb pairing, just in what I consider an unusual order.  The speaker has a formal British accent and so I assume this is a common expression for that dialect.  As an American, I would have said **coming shortly**, (i.e. "coming soon")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a normal adverb/verb pairing, just in what I consider an unusual order.  The speaker has a formal British accent, appropriate to the senior staff of a fancy hotel, so we can assume he is speaking "proper" English for that dialect.  As an American, however, I would have said *coming shortly*, (i.e. "coming soon").

"We have" is an indirect, and therefore somewhat formal/polite way to say "is/are".

> The Emperor and Empress of Japan **are** coming soon.

The use of "have" suggests that this is a special *honor* for the subject, as if it is an experience they are proud to *own*.  As a related example, suppose someone is doing a show and they notice a celebrity in the audience, who they want to acknowledge:

> I see **we have** with us in the audience tonight the noted star of stage and screen, Hugh Jackman!

---

I would have also put *"constantly"* before *"frequent"*.

> Princess Charles and Di ... used to **constantly frequent** the hotel

Note that in this sentence "frequent" is used as a *verb*, another formal phrasing:

> **[frequent](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/frequent)** (v): Visit (a place) often.